# How can I replace multiple whitespace with a single space in Perl?

Tags: perl

Why is this not working?

```
$data = "What    is the STATUS of your mind right now?";

$data =~ tr/ +/ /;

print $data;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `$data =~ s/ +/ /;` instead.

Explanation:

The `tr` is the [translation](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html) operator. An important thing to note about this is that regex modifiers do not apply in a translation statement (excepting `-` which still indicates a range). So when you use
`tr/ +/ /` you're saying "Take every instance of the characters space and `+` and translate them to a space". In other words, the `tr` thinks of the space and `+` as individual characters, **not** a regular expression.

Demonstration:

```
$data = "What    is the STA++TUS of your mind right now?";

$data =~ tr/ +/ /;

print $data; #Prints "What    is the STA  TUS of your mind right now?"
```

Using `s` does what you're looking for, by saying "match any number of consecutive spaces (at least one instance) and substitute them with a single space". You may also want to use something like
`s/ +/ /g;` if there's more than one place you want the substitution to occur (`g` meaning to apply globally).

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `tr` with the "squash" option, which will remove duplicate replaced characters. See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for details.

```
my $s = "foo      bar   fubb";
$s =~ tr/ //s;
```

Answer (score 10):

Perl 5.10 has a new character class, `\h`, the stands for horizontal whitespace which is nice for this sort of thing:

```
 $s =~ s/\h+/ /g;
```